# Wrapping text inside irregular shapes

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-shapes

I was wondering if there is a library that anyone is aware of that can handle wrapping text inside custom shapes?

I'm attempting to build a module for a friends site that deals with engraving on jewellery. This module would need to be able to **preview to the customer in real time** what their text would look like on the product.

As the Jewellery comes in different shapes and sizes, I need a way to wrap the entered text to inside different custom shapes like in the image below.

[image: Example]

I've already coded a prototype in JavaScript that works for the most part, but its pretty rough around the edges and I was hoping for a more *tried and tested* way to do this instead.

I need to make this work on as many browsers as possible.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You would need to use [**CSS shapes**](https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/) to achieve this. You would then need to use JavaScript to write the calculations to the CSS itself.

Comment: https://skeate.github.io/2015/07/13/Wrapping-Text-to-Fit-Shaped-Containers-with-CSS.html

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I did see CSS shapes while I was researching how to do this but I thought I read that its not very compatible with older browsers? Is this the best option then?

Comment: Yes, CSS Shapes is probably your best bet. You could try SVG but might be more [trouble than it's worth](https://jsfiddle.net/jqowv4b5/). You can't simply update the markup, you'd have to update the source file and re-output.

Comment: You can also use canvas 2D context, and thanks to measureText method decide when break it, but it's slow if you have update it according to window resize etc. in Mozilla (I'be tried not long ago an even MS Edge works fine). But the simplest way is to use SVG and CSS.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to achieve this effect without JavaScript, basically by using the CSS [`shape-outside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside) property, as already mentioned in the comments.

### How it works

The important elements are displayed in the following image (a screenshot of my web inspector):

[image]

You create a `.wrapper` element that contains an SVG element, two shape elements and a text paragraph. According to your shape, you can position your SVG element absolute and give it a lower `z-index` than your text paragraph.

The text wrapping itself is possible due to the `shape-outside` property in combination with `float`. One possible solution is to create to elements, give them an outside shape that toughly matches the SVG shape and let them float to the left and to the right, such as the text is in between and wraps on both sides.

**The Good** about this approach is, that without any further calculation the text wraps according to the shape. You can even scale the wrapper element and due to percentage values, the shape will scale accordingly. **The Bad** is, that you would have to create a corresponding CSS shape for each of the products and you will have to handle the text, that doesn't fit into the shape (which could be easily solved with `overflow: hidden;`). Also even a year after this question was asked, the [browser support for `shape-outside`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes) isn't that well either. But you can use the corresponding vendor prefixes (e.g. `-webkit-shape-outside`). [SVG is well supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg) now.

### Working example

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: -65px;
  left: 28px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 90%;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

.shape {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 95%, 20% 40%, 10% 20%, 20% 0);
  float: left;
}

.right {
  shape-outside: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 95%, 80% 40%, 90% 20%, 80% 0);
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg class="background" viewbox="-1 -1 95 95">
    <path d="M60,30 a30,30 0 0,1 0,60 L0,90 0,30 a30,30 0 0,1 60,0z" fill="#daeef3" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
  </svg>
  <div class="shape left"></div>
  <div class="shape right"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis impedit libero esse odio excepturi fuga est ut itaque a quod suscipit, rerum asperi ores. Lorem ipsum dolor sit am</p>
</div>
```